# How to get full json content of a HTTPWebRequest using c# if its giving only partial content at the moment?

Tags: c#, json, range, httpwebrequest

The API is resulting only partial content from the URL. It has loads of data in it but it is giving me 20 at a time. When I change the range header it ignores it. Is there any way we can fix this? I used following code:

```
            dynamic jsonObject;
            string username = "username";
            string password = "password";
            string url = "url";
            string stringTest = string.Format(url);


            HttpWebRequest req = 
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(stringTest);
            WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = req.Headers;


            //req.AddRange(10, 100);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}: 
            {password}"));
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string stringResultTest = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                jsonObject = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringResultTest);
            }
```

Comment: can you drop a code snippet of how you are sending the request?

Comment: I have added the code now..